# __iterm2_precmd:type:50: bad option: -t

Tags: terminal, iterm2

After upgrading to Big Sur i have started getting the below error every time I open iterm2 or run any command in the terminal

__iterm2_precmd:type:50: bad option: -t

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly this issue. I had previously switched to zsh and deleting the ~/.iterm2_shell_integration.bash file solved it for me.
Others have had success reinstalling iterm2 or re-running from the menu: iTerm2 > Install Shell Integration.
Source: https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/-/issues/8089